# Terminal snap resizing issue

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal

I like having multiple terminal windows above having tabs, so I tile them up into separate corners.

Now my question is if there's a way to fix these [gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUbZY.png) that occur when snapping to corners.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 (4.2.0-23-generic). It only happens with the terminal window, other applications do it without gaps.

Manually aligning by resizing doesn't work either, it moves in character increments.

To me it seems like an unnecessary limitation, seeing as the window resizes perfectly to the edges if snapped to the bottom or top of the screen, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATkHN.png).

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [Terminator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/terminator/)?

```
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

You can then split your terminal in so many tiles as you wish. Just click with the right mouse button on the terminator window and split the window either horizontally or vertically.